# Getting statusCode of 400 from GET

Tags: android, android-asynctask, get

I am trying to do a get from the API, but it returns a 400, I have tried putting my local IP and putting 10.0.2.2, but he has continued to do the same, in the Event Log shows me this too: **Emulator: CANNOT TRANSLATE guest DNS ip**.From the PostMan I get the JSON back correctly so I do not think the problem is in the API

This is where I do everything

```
    public void PendingTrajects(){


     AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
       String URL = "http://ip:port/api/trajectes";
       client.get(this, URL, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

       @Override
       public void onStart() {
           Toast.makeText(PendingTrajectRecyclerView.this, "Carregant...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

       @Override
       public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
           JSONArray Usuaris = new JSONArray();
           JSONArray trajectes = new JSONArray();

           String Nom = null;

           String strResponseBody = new String(responseBody);

           try {
               //Usuari = new JSONArray(strResponseBody);
               trajectes = new JSONArray(strResponseBody);
           }catch (JSONException e){
               Toast.makeText(PendingTrajectRecyclerView.this, "Error a la connexió", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }

           try {
               for(int i = 0; i < trajectes.length(); i++){
                   JSONObject trajecte = trajectes.getJSONObject(i);
                   JSONArray realitzas = trajecte.getJSONArray("realitzas");
                   for(int j = 0; j < realitzas.length(); j++){
                       JSONObject realitza = realitzas.getJSONObject(j);
                       JSONObject usuari = realitza.getJSONObject("usuari");
                       Log.d("xd", ""+usuari.getString("name"));
                   }
               }
           }catch (JSONException e){
               Toast.makeText(PendingTrajectRecyclerView.this, "Error a la connexió", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
           Toast.makeText(PendingTrajectRecyclerView.this, "Error a la connexió ONFailure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           Log.d("Error",""+statusCode);
       }

   });
```

Comment: `400= Bad Request`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Yeah I know, but I tried without the code in the method onSuccess and still failing

Comment: first, try to check your full address if it works in a browser, using some network monitoring software, such as [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) . If error 400 still happens, you have to check the api.

Comment: @NlCedar, Yeah I tried on the browser and Postman and returns 200

Comment: @Lluís check your parameters

Comment: @Lluís Make sure internet is present or not?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya it's present, now I'm trying to change the IP of the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`400 BAD REQUEST`**](https://httpstatuses.com/400)

> The server cannot or will not process the request due to something
>   that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request
>   syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request
>   routing).

You should [**`DEBUG`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/) your Application. Check your parameters.
Add a Break-point here

```
 String URL = "http://ip:port/api/trajectes";
```

Actually server could not understand the request due to **`invalid syntax`**.

Comment: I did it too and seems like everything is okay. I'm desperate, I don't know what else to prove

Comment: Seems like the problem is on the IP because the event log returns this: Emulator: CANNOT TRANSLATE guest DNS ip but with the local IP return 0 and with the 10.0.2.2 returns 400, and idk what can be

Comment: @Lluís `10.0.2.2 ` is local address

Comment: The only solution I've found has been putting the api in the cloud, but now doesn't work on the second try catch, you know what can be?

Comment: Solved, I was not calling the name well, thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't have enough reputation, sorry